# getting this error while loading a tensorflow project

Tags: python, tensorflow, github, flask, websocket

getting a error while a installing a tensorflow python project from https://github.com/victordibia/skyfall
first i tried to install the requiremnt.txt file i got **Could not detect requirement name for 'git+https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server.git', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name** error,

then i removed the last line of txt file, then getting this

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 18, in 
    from utils import web_socket_server
  File "C:\Users\anurag\Downloads\skyfall-master\utils\web_socket_server.py", line 4, in 
    from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SimpleWebSocketServer'**

after that i installed git , now getting this

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 19, in 
    from utils import web_socket_client
  File "C:\Users\anurag\Downloads\skyfall-master\utils\web_socket_client.py", line 8, in 
    from websocket import WebSocketException, WebSocketConnectionClosedException
ImportError: cannot import name 'WebSocketException'**

Comment: You are missing a dependency. See  https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server for how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you have not installed this package: https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server

Try this to install it(you must have [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) installed and also [git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)) and then run the project again:

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server.git
```

Comment: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server.git C:\Users\anurag\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h7d1v5mx
Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

Comment: @ÅnűrağÝadųvãnshï You must also install git. See edit

Comment: how to install git

Comment: sir first when i trired to install requirement.txt..i got this error "Could not detect requirement name for 'git+https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server.git', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name",

Comment: File "app.py", line 19, in <module>
    from utils import web_socket_client
  File "C:\Users\anurag\Downloads\skyfall-master\utils\web_socket_client.py", line 8, in <module>
    from websocket import WebSocketException, WebSocketConnectionClosedException
ImportError: cannot import name 'WebSocketException'

Comment: @ÅnűrağÝadųvãnshï You can see this link to install git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git